# Some pages hide content unless "Read more" is clicked

Tags: navigation

If I have multiple pages on Drupal, some show the full page, and others say "Read more" and will only show the whole page when it is clicked. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the size of the content of the page or how long it is. What's up with that?

Answer (score 0):

What you're probably looking at is a "View". This view is probably showing a list of "Content" (nodes).

Now each node is probably being set to render in "Teaser" view mode. But since some of your node types (`article` for example) doesn't have a "teaser" view mode configured, it shows the "Full" (or "Default") view mode, which renders the "whole" thing.

What you need to do is find the View Mode that your content listing View is using, the Node Type of the content that's showing up as Full, (for example 'Basic Page'), then go to:

**Structure > Content Types > [Content Type you want to configure] > Manage Display**

And configure the view mode that your View is using to display the Read More link, show the body text as "Summary or Trimmed" etc.